# "TIMED_WAITING" thread state when connecting via SSH using JSCH

Tags: java, multithreading, ssh, jsch, thread-dump

I'm trying to connect to another server via SSH with JSCH library, execute some command there (check current date with TZ) and return result.

Code looks like this:

```
private String processSSHCommand(String host, int port, String user, String password, String command) throws JSchException, IOException {
                Session session = new JSch().getSession(user, host, port);
                session.setPassword(password);
                Properties config = new Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(config);
                session.connect();
                ChannelExec channel = ((ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec"));
                channel.setCommand(command);
                channel.connect();
                String s = IOUtils.toString(channel.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                channel.disconnect();
                session.disconnect();
                return s;
            }
```

There's my thread dump when this code is stuck:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" #35 daemon prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb3d4509000 nid=0xc87 in Object.wait() [0x00007fb3ec9d1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:326)
 - locked <0x00000007bcad22a0> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
 - locked <0x00000007bcad22a0> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
 - locked <0x00000007bcad5168> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
 at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1128)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1104)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1078)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:382)
 ...processSSHCommand(...)
```

Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: If you have some methods or blocks with synchronization  please share it

Comment: What is the `command`? What does it do?

Comment: Martin, command is simple - "date +'%:z'"

Answer (score 0):

You code works perfectly I've just run it in main method. As I can see you run it under weblogic so it could be a cause.

I'm not sure exactly but I would suggest you try this one:

```
ChannelExec channel = ((ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec"));
channel.setInputStream(null); // set to null
channel.setCommand(command);
channel.connect();
```